# If my server PDC Emulater is down then how to re up PDC again functioning?

Tags: active-directory

My pdc emulater is down so plz guide me how to bring up pdc and it working fine.
This question also asking many time from interviewer. so plz guide me all total way to solve this.

Comment: Please make at least a little effort to explain WTF are you talking about...

Comment: Is your PDC emulator actually down, or are you only asking for future job interviews?

Answer (score 2):

***Assuming*** you are talking about a domain controller which holds the PDC Emulator role and is broken beyond repair, you need to seize the role, i.e. forcefully transfer it to another domain controller in the same domain.

As documented [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785114(v=ws.10).aspx), you can do that using `ntdsutil`:

1. Open Command Prompt.
2. Type:
   `ntdsutil`
3. At the ntdsutil command prompt, type:
   `roles`
4. At the fsmo maintenance command prompt, type:
   `connections`
5. At the server connections command prompt, type:
   `connect to server`*DomainController*
   (where *DomainController* is the name of another domain controller in the same domain)
6. At the server connections prompt, type:
   `quit`
7. At the fsmo maintenance command prompt, type:
   `seize PDC`